# Snowflake: Fail COPY INTO incase of error limit while loading?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Is it possible to set the error limit while loading the data into a snowflake table. I am using COPY INTO option. I know there are options like `RETURN_FAILED_ONLY` and `VALIDATION_MODE`, but this does not support if the error limit is reached then fail COPY INTO else continue loading it by ignoring the failed records.

Comment: I don't think we have option for that, as work around execute the copy command at end copy command check the error count if count is acceptable then commit the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the SKIP_FILE_num or SKIP_FILE_num%. This will skip the file when a certain number of records or certain % of records fail.  When a file is skipped it will be listed with a status of FAILED.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Snowflake does not currently have the equivalent that you are looking for across all files of a load. Depending on how you are scripting/executing your COPY INTO commands, however, you could wrap the COPY INTO command with a transaction, check the output of the COPY INTO, determine whether it is inside or outside of your threshold and then either commit or rollback the transaction. This would accomplish what you are looking for, but takes a bit of custom coding to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks, Mike for the answer, it looks like `SKIP_FILE` will skip that one file but still load data from other files and won't fail the entire COPY INTO command? I am looking for a wholistic fail mode if the number of the error has reached a certain limit in COPY INTO command.

Comment: I see there is a error_limit in the output https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#output of the COPY INTO command but is there a way to apply ERROR_LIMIT in the COPY_INTO command itself so it fail once the limit is reached.

Comment: So, you're saying that if you have 10 files, and 1 of them has >100 errors, and you want to fail for >100 errors, you'd want none of the 10 file to be loaded?  If that is the case, I'd probably need to test the SKIP_FILE_num parameter to see if it is truly by file or by the batch of files.

Comment: Let say, the ERROR_LIMIT is set to 100, and there are 5 files, first file have 20 errors, second file have 30 errors, third file have 70 errors and in the fourth and fifth there are no errors, but *combined* there are 120 which is > than 100. In this case the entire COPY INTO operation should fail skipping all the files. This functionality is in Teradata https://docs.teradata.com/reader/yxBNqiK9WZh15WoRzMnBrw/yv6TgTN0eUZsg5GmyfD_pw I am looking for an equivalent option in Snowflake

Comment: The example I gave above is similar to what you the example you gave, just that the errors might be distributed in multiple files.

Comment: Snowflake does not currently have the equivalent that you are looking for.  Depending on how you are scripting/executing your COPY INTO commands, however, you could wrap the COPY INTO command with a transaction, check the output of the COPY INTO, determine whether it is inside or outside of your threshold and then either commit or rollback the transaction.  This would accomplish what you are looking for, but takes a bit of custom coding to accomplish.